# MySql: How to fix mysql query with group_concat with Sum?

Tags: mysql

**Requirement:**

I am trying to enhance the sql query with group_contact and sum. But I could not succeed.

**SQL Query:**

```
 SELECT 
    team.application_name AS 'Project',
    regression.automated_test_type AS 'SuiteType',
    SUM(regression.total_testcases) AS 'Total',
    SUM(regression.passed_testcases) AS 'Passed',
    SUM(regression.failed_testcases) AS 'Failed',
    regression.test_environment AS 'Environment'
FROM
    regression,
    team
WHERE
    execution_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
        AND regression.automated_test_type <> 'Regression'
        AND regression.report_link NOT LIKE '%Automation_Q002envHc%'
        AND regression.report_link NOT LIKE '%LitVmEnvHealthChecks%'
        AND team.application_id = regression.regression_application_id
        AND team.application_name <> 'Not Mapped'
GROUP BY regression_application_id , regression.test_environment
ORDER BY team.application_name ASC , regression.automated_test_type ASC , regression.test_environment ASC;
```

**Current Query Output:**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Project         SuiteType             Total Passed Failed Environment
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Application 1   Health Check            30    22    8     IQA
Application 2   Build Validation Test   33    21    12    IQA
Application 2   Build Validation Test   24    11    13    PROD
Application 3   Build Validation Test   399   321   78    IQA
```

**Expected Output**

```
------------------------------------------------------
Project         SuiteType               Environment
------------------------------------------------------
Application 1   Health Check            IQA->30,22,8
Application 2   Build Validation Test   IQA->33,21,12|PROD->24,11,13  
Application 3   Build Validation Test   IQA->399,321,78
```

I edited the query based on the comments and answers. Still no luck.

**EDITED ANSWER BASED ON THE COMMENTS**

```
     SELECT 
    T.Project,
    T.SuiteType,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(T.Environment,
                '->',
                T.Passed,
                ',',
                T.Failed)
        ORDER BY T.Environment
        SEPARATOR '|') AS 'Environment'
FROM
    (SELECT 
        team.application_name AS 'Project',
            regression.automated_test_type AS 'SuiteType',
            SUM(regression.passed_testcases) AS 'Passed',
            SUM(regression.failed_testcases) AS 'Failed',
            regression.test_environment AS 'Environment'
    FROM
        regression, team
    WHERE
        execution_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
            AND regression.automated_test_type <> 'Regression'
            AND regression.report_link NOT LIKE '%Automation_Q002envHc%'
            AND regression.report_link NOT LIKE '%LitVmEnvHealthChecks%'
            AND team.application_id = regression.regression_application_id
            AND team.application_name <> 'Not Mapped'
    GROUP BY regression_application_id , regression.test_environment
    ORDER BY team.application_name ASC , regression.automated_test_type ASC , regression.test_environment ASC) T
GROUP BY T.Project , T.SuiteType
ORDER BY T.Project , T.SuiteType
```

Comment: what is `Environment` in your expected output? a string?

Comment: Yes. Concatenated string with Sum of the total,pass and fail for each environment.

Comment: 1) What have you tried? 2. Are you sure you want to do this in MySQL? It may be more efficient to do such transformations in the application code.

Comment: You nailed it. I had an idea to implement in the application layer. Before that, I would like to give a try in the SQL. So that It would be easy to implement in the application.

Comment: when you use `FROM   ( SELECT query ) as T` you need to include the alias for the subquery  `as T` where `T` is any name you like

Comment: Sweet Sweet. It worked. How stupid I was? I did not read the answer properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, it looks like the desired output column is a concatenation of expressions already being returned and some literals

```
SELECT ...
     , CONCAT( expr1 , '->' , expr2 , ',' , expr3 , ',' , expr4 ) AS `Environment` 
  FROM ...
```

--

Something like this:

```
SELECT ...
     , CONCAT( regression.test_environment
             , '->'
             , SUM(regression.total_testcases)
             , ','
             , SUM(regression.passed_testcases)
             , ','
             , SUM(regression.failed_testcases)
       ) AS `Environment` 
  FROM ...
```

Note that is any of those expressions evaluate to `NULL`, the return from the CONCAT will be NULL. And we would probably want to add some handling for the NULL case, such as using the IFNULL function, or CONCAT_WS in place of CONCAT.

---

To get the "grouping" by `Project` and `TestSuite`, one option is to take the query above, and reference it as an inline view in an outer query:

```
SELECT v.Project
     , v.SuiteType
     , GROUP_CONCAT(v.Environment ORDER BY v.Environment SEPARATOR '|') AS Environment
  FROM ( -- inline view query
         SELECT ...
              , CONCAT( regression.test_environment
                      , '->'
                      , SUM(regression.total_testcases)
                      , ','
                      , SUM(regression.passed_testcases)
                      , ','
                      , SUM(regression.failed_testcases)
                ) AS `Environment` 
           FROM ...

       ) v
 GROUP 
    BY v.Project
     , v.SuiteType  
 ORDER
    BY v.Project
     , v.SuiteType
```

Comment: You miss the grouping of `IQA->33,21,12|PROD->24,11,13`

Comment: Yes. Missed the grouping

Comment: example of how to get the "grouping" added to answer.

Comment: Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Updated the sql based on your answer. Still no luck.

Comment: Looks like you missed the **`v`** following the closing paren of the inline view query. MySQL calls the inline view a "derived table", and requires that a table alias be assigned to it. The example query in my answer assigns the alias **`v`**.

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/PJR93629)**

`Table1` is your current query output. You could replace it with

```
FROM (SELECT <current query>) as T
```

**SQL QUERY**

```
SELECT `Project`, 
       `SuiteType`, 
       GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(`Environment`,'->', `Total`, ',', `Passed`, ',', `Failed`) 
                     ORDER BY `Environment`
                     SEPARATOR '|'
                   ) as `Environment`
FROM  Table1
GROUP BY `Project`, `SuiteType`
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Unable to sum the inside the group_concat

Comment: Updated the query. Still no luck,Thx

Comment: what you mean? there isnt any sum there. Did you see the demo?

Comment: I checked. My actual query have sum which i need to concat. My apologies, If i misunderstood.

Comment: You need to include the alias for the subquery, check the second line on my answer.